# Converting Oracle Report (6i)into Excel

Tags: oraclereports

While generating oracle report in excel, it works fine. But column header are repeating as first column?

Answer (score 0):

repeating header in excel may caused by two reasons
you may put the header in repeating frame, or you put it inside the loop which you get the result to excel, so you have to get it out to write it only once at the beggening .

also check your code about second column header and other columns, if this not true put additional info about your report here.